# VS 2015 .Net core Migration

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using dotnet ef migrations add [abc] command add migration but it gives following error: No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef"

I have tried from command prompt as well as package manager console
but gives same error. 
I have checked the path as well, i'm running command where my project.json sits.

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer is already installed.

project.json code is as follows:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "dependencies": {
    "Bloomerang.Domain": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.1"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },
  "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
    "imports": [
      "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50",
      "portable-net45+win8"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: The command is `dotnet ef migrations add {MigrationName}` (without hyphen) and not `dotnet-ef`. See here for a tutorial: http://benjii.me/2016/05/dotnet-ef-migrations-for-asp-net-core/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to use .NET Core CLI commands then your `project.json` should include the below items. Specially the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design` package.I cannot see it on your file.So you need to install it before use those commands.

**project.json**

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": {
            "type": "build",
            "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
        }
    },

    "tools": {
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
    },

    "frameworks": {
        "netcoreapp1.0": { }
    }
}
```